# Зачем нужны Асинхронные итераторы в Python?

Tags: python, asyncio

Потихоньку разбираясь с библиотекой asyncio наткнулся на "асинхронные" итераторы. Посмотрев примеры написал простой итератор и точно такой же, но "асинхронный". После запуска скрипта я Не обнаружил никакой разницы между асинхронным и обычным итератором.

Вывод:

```
async
wait for Andrey 2c
wait for Alex 2c
wait for Artem 2c
Time: 6.04335618019104

No async
wait for Andrey 2c
wait for Alex 2c
wait for Artem 2c
Time: 6.024480581283569
```

```
import asyncio
import time


class Iterator:
    def __init__(self, delay, people: list[str]):
        self._people = people
        self.delay = delay
        self._i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._i >= len(self._people):
            raise StopIteration

        human = self._people[self._i]
        self._i += 1

        time.sleep(self.delay)

        return f"wait for {human} {self.delay}c"


class Crowd:
    def __init__(self, delay, people: list[str]):
        self._people = people
        self.delay = delay
        self._i = 0

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        if self._i >= len(self._people):
            raise StopAsyncIteration

        human = self._people[self._i]
        self._i += 1

        await asyncio.sleep(self.delay)

        return f"wait for {human} {self.delay}c"


async def amain():
    crowd = Crowd(2, ["Andrey", "Alex", "Artem"])
    async for i in crowd:
        print(i)


def main():
    iterr = Iterator(2, ["Andrey", "Alex", "Artem"])
    for i in iterr:
        print(i)


begin = time.time()

print("async")
asyncio.run(amain())

print("Time:", time.time() - begin)
begin = time.time()

print("\nNo async")
main()

print("Time:", time.time() - begin)
```

В моём понимании при первой асинхронной итерации должен вызваться метод `__anext__` и дойдя до `await asyncio.sleep(delay)` должна происходить следующая итерация, так как `asyncio.sleep(delay)` передаёт управление следующим task-ам (как в примере ниже), но этого не происходит.
Вопрос: зачем тогда нужен асинхронный итератор, если обычный итератор даёт такие же результаты по времени?

```
async def sleep(i):
    print(f"({i}) start")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)


async def main():
    tasks = [sleep(i) for i in range(1, 6)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Он вполне передаёт управление следующим task'ам, но у вас здесь есть всего один task, который ждёт, пока закончится asyncio.sleep, поэтому ничего особенного и не происходит

Comment: Но у вас в первом примере выполняется всего одна задача и конечно она занимает столько же времени сколько и обычный sleep. Вот если бы вы одновременно с amain() запустили одновременно какую нибудь другую асинхронную задачу, то она могла бы выполняться в то время, когда amain спит на очередной итерации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короткий пример с вашим же кодом - асинхронное одновременное выполнение *двадцати* ваших итераторов за тоже самое время, что выполняется один итератор:

```py
# asyncio.run(amain())
asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(*[amain() for _ in range(20)]))
```

Если у вас остальной код будет асинхронный, то использование асинхронных конструкций позволит выполнять код [почти] параллельно, причём это возможно даже без использования дополнительных потоков, даже в одном потоке. Пока в одном месте производится асинхронное ожидание ввода-вывода или работает асинхронный `sleep`, в другом месте программы может выполняться другой код. В моём примере параллельно выполняются 20 веток кода, поскольку код в основном спит всё это время, это практически не тратит ресурсы процессора.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ, который дал понять суть асинхронных итераторов. Для себя сделал такой вывод: асинхронные итераторы работают точно так же как и обычные, но отличаются тем, что можно вызывать и другие асинхронные функции. Это происходит потому, что итератор является одним task-ом (Спасибо @Mike), а это значит, что параллельно ему можно вызвать на исполнение другие task-и.
Думаю я разобрался, Спасибо всем за ответы!